# Admin Password can't be changed

Tags: settings

Can't change the admin password from the admin account...maybe in terminal, but not in GUI.  The only way I've found is to create a standard account and change admin password from there.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'admin' you mean root?

If so, one way to do it is by being logged on a terminal with a user who can elevate privileges(sudo) is to:

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

That should allow you to change root's password. The other option is to 'become' root and then do a passwd:

```
$ sudo su
# passwd
```